# R extracting values based on match between columns

Tags: r

I have two CSVs with data from two sessions of an experiment. The first CSV contains participant ID numbers and experimental conditions. The second CSV contains ID numbers only. Not all participants showed up for the second session, so the second CSV is smaller. Each CSV has unique columns containing participants' responses.

So the first set is something like

```
X = data.frame(ID = 1:20, Condition = rep(c('a','b','c','d','e'), length.out=20), Response1 = rep('xyz', length.out=20), Response2 = rep('abc', length.out=20))
```

And the second

```
Y = data.frame(ID = 1:14, delayed.response = rep('def', length.out=14))
```

I want to create a column in Y for conditions that matches IDs with the correct condition. I've tried various strategies (match(), grep(), Y['Condition'] = X$Condition[X$ID==Y$ID], Y['Condition'] = X$Condition[Y$ID %in% X$ID] etc), but they either fail, or match IDs with the wrong condition. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This is just a simple merge: `merge(Y,X)`

Comment: There are numerous columns unique to each CSV, so I don't think merge would be appropriate here. I'll alter the original post to better reflect the data.

Comment: That doesn't change anything really. What's wrong with `merge(Y,X)`. Is it that you only want the condition from `X`? Then `merge(Y, X[, c("ID","Condition")])` should do.

Comment: `merge` is the way to go. Otherwise, a simple match could get you there: `Y$Condition <- X$Condition[match(Y$ID,X$ID)]`

Comment: Strangely, merge worked for the example I gave above, but yields a length(nrow(X)*nrow(Y)) response with the actual data. 

thelatemail: your suggestion worked perfectly. Thankyou!